# How can I make this code work faster ? (searching large corpus of text for large words)

Tags: python, optimization, time, performance

in Python, I have created a text generator that acts on certain parameters but my code is -at most of the time- slow and performs below my expectations. I expect one sentence per every 3-4 minutes but it fails to comply if the database it works on is large -I use the project Gutenberg's 18-book corpus and I will create my custom corpus and add further books so performance is vital.- The algorithm and the implementation is below:

ALGORITHM

1- Enter the trigger sentence -only once, at the beginning of the program-

2- Get the longest word in the trigger sentence

3- Find all the sentences of the corpus that contain the word at step2

4- Randomly select one of those sentences

5- Get the sentence (named sentA to resolve the ambiguity in description) that follows the sentence picked at step4 -so long as sentA is longer than 40 characters-

6- Go to step 2, now the trigger sentence is the sentA of step5

IMPLEMENTATION

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from random import choice

triggerSentence = raw_input("Please enter the trigger sentence:")#get input sentence from user

previousLongestWord = ""

listOfSents = gutenberg.sents()
listOfWords = gutenberg.words()
corpusSentences = [] #all sentences in the related corpus

sentenceAppender = ""

longestWord = ""

#this function is not mine, code courtesy of Dave Kirby, found on the internet about sorting list without duplication speed tricks
def arraySorter(seq):
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]


def findLongestWord(longestWord):
    if(listOfWords.count(longestWord) == 1 or longestWord.upper() == previousLongestWord.upper()):
        longestWord = sortedSetOfValidWords[-2]
        if(listOfWords.count(longestWord) == 1):
            longestWord = sortedSetOfValidWords[-3]


doappend = corpusSentences.append

def appending():

    for mysentence in listOfSents: #sentences are organized into array so they can actually be read word by word.
        sentenceAppender = " ".join(mysentence)
        doappend(sentenceAppender)


appending()
sentencesContainingLongestWord = []

def getSentence(longestWord, sentencesContainingLongestWord):


    for sentence in corpusSentences:
        if sentence.count(longestWord):#if the sentence contains the longest target string, push it into the sentencesContainingLongestWord list
            sentencesContainingLongestWord.append(sentence)


def lengthCheck(sentenceIndex, triggerSentence, sentencesContainingLongestWord):

    while(len(corpusSentences[sentenceIndex + 1]) < 40):#in case the next sentence is shorter than 40 characters, pick another trigger sentence
        sentencesContainingLongestWord.remove(triggerSentence)
        triggerSentence = choice(sentencesContainingLongestWord)
        sentenceIndex = corpusSentences.index(triggerSentence)

while len(triggerSentence) > 0: #run the loop as long as you get a trigger sentence

    sentencesContainingLongestWord = []#all the sentences that include the longest word are to be inserted into this set

    setOfValidWords = [] #set for words in a sentence that exists in a corpus                    

    split_str = triggerSentence.split()#split the sentence into words

    setOfValidWords = [word for word in split_str if listOfWords.count(word)]

    sortedSetOfValidWords = arraySorter(sorted(setOfValidWords, key = len))

    longestWord = sortedSetOfValidWords[-1]

    findLongestWord(longestWord)

    previousLongestWord = longestWord

    getSentence(longestWord, sentencesContainingLongestWord)

    triggerSentence = choice(sentencesContainingLongestWord)

    sentenceIndex = corpusSentences.index(triggerSentence)

    lengthCheck(sentenceIndex, triggerSentence, sentencesContainingLongestWord)

    triggerSentence = corpusSentences[sentenceIndex + 1]#get the sentence that is next to the previous trigger sentence

    print triggerSentence
    print "\n"

    corpusSentences.remove(triggerSentence)#in order to view the sentence index numbers, you can remove this one so index numbers are concurrent with actual gutenberg numbers


print "End of session, please rerun the program"
#initiated once the while loop exits, so that the program ends without errors
```

The computer I run the code on is a bit old, dual-core CPU was bought in Feb. 2006 and 2x512 RAM was bought in Sept. 2004 so I'm not sure if my implementation is bad or the hardware is a reason for the slow runtime. Any ideas on how I can rescue this from its hazardous form ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd highly reccomend looking into the algorithms on this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: Plenty of slow operations in your code, but the question is which ones are worth optimizing. See http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html to find out.

Comment: [This will find which part of your code is costing the most](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think my first advice must be: Think carefully about what your routines do, and make sure the name describes that. Currently you have things like:

- `arraySorter` which neither deals with [arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) nor sorts (it's an implementation of [nub](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/nub_f.html))
- `findLongestWord` which counts things or selects words by criteria not present in the algorithm description, yet ends up doing nothing at all because longestWord is a local variable (argument, as it were)
- `getSentence` which appends an arbitrary number of sentences onto a list
- `appending` which sounds like it might be a state checker, but operates only through side effects
- considerable confusion between local and global variables, for instance the global variable `sentenceAppender` is never used, nor is it an actor (for instance, a function) like the name suggests

For the task itself, what you really need are indices. It might be overkill to index every word - technically you should only need index entries for words that occur as the longest word of a sentence. Dictionaries are your primary tool here, and the second tool is lists. Once you have those indices, looking up a random sentence containing any given word takes only a dictionary lookup, a [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice), and a list lookup. Perhaps a few list lookups, given the sentence length restriction.

This example should prove a good object lesson that modern hardware or optimizers like Psyco do not solve algorithmic problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) speeds up the execution?

Comment: Definitely worth a try. It's basically free optimization with little to no effort.